# Clear Textboxes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-controls

Morning All,

I would like to have a cancel button on my web page that essentially i would like to clear form field and themn redirect users to the home page.

I have 7 txt boxes that i will need to clear before the page redirects.   I have done some searching on the internets and have tried to put the following sample into my page with no luck....

With this code i get an error on the X = "" line.  I get a message 'Value of type string cannt be converted to system.we.UI.control'

```
 Protected Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click

         Dim x As Control
           For Each x In Me.Controls
         If TypeOf x Is TextBox Then
           x = " "
         End If

         Next

 End Sub
```

And i have also tried the below which also produces a Compilation Error.

```
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            DirectCast(c, TextBox).Text = ""
        End If
        Next
```

Can anyone help me with resolving this issue?

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim x As Control
For Each x In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf x Is TextBox Then
    Dim txt as TextBox = x
    txt.Text = ""
  End If
Next
```

Explanation:
You tried to set a string to a `Control`-variable and of course the compiler does not know how to to this.
The version I gave will set the Text-property of each TextBox to the empty-String

Answer (score 1):

You can use html code to reset all field of current form you are working with

use follwoing code to reset all fields

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="redirectFunction()" />
```

and in redirectFunction write following javascript code:

```
function redirectFunction()
{
window.location="destination.aspx";
}
```

using above code you can redirect to destination page.